# Как отправить письмо таким образом, что бы оно не попало в папку спам?

Tags: php, email, gmail, рассылка

Здравствуйте, уважаемые коллеги!

Отправляю письмо при помощи SwiftMailer. Проблема заключается в том, что все письма, которые приходят с моего сервера попадают в папку со спамом, да и к тому же внизу появляется желтая табличка с надписью

> *Возможно, это письмо не было отправлено с адреса [мой адресс]*

. 
Как это исправить? Перечитал все, что только можно, но так и не нашел решение. Письмо отправлял с самых разных ящиков gmail. Вот так выглядит код, который и организовывает отправку письма:

```
// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('aspmx.l.google.com', 25))
  ->setUsername('gmail1@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('***********')
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
  ->setFrom(['gmail1 => 'Jack Shcherbakov'])
  ->setTo(['gmail2'=> 'Jack Shcherbakov'])
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
?>
```

А вот так выглядит само письмо:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее выражаю огромную благодарность всем, кто поможет!

Comment: Письмо в спам отправляет почтовый клиент адресата. Которым ты управлять никак не можешь. *вот так выглядит само письмо* Заголовки письма надо показывать... вообще-то.

Comment: @Akina почтовый клиент адресата, отправляющий письмо в спам - это очень частный случай. В спам отправляют антиспам системы почтовых серверов, и у того же гугла это именно так. Но заголовки письма, да, надо показывать.

Comment: @Akina Проблема не в клинте! При чем тут он вообще... Проблема в том, как именно письмо отправляется.

Comment: А вы настроили DKIM записи для почтового ящика?

Comment: DKIM как и SPF настраивается не для почтового ящика, а для почтового сервера.

Comment: @ Алексей Кузнецов - разумеется настроил. Да и это вроде бы не имеет значения для работы SwiftMailer. Он никак с этим не пересикается. Это имеет значение в основном при работе со встроенной функцией  mail() php.

Comment: @JackShcherbakov И тем не менее - где заголовки слитого в спам письма? Только по ним можно понять, что могло не понравиться антиспам-фильтрам. Дополнительно - при отправки на почтовый адрес в том же домене (gmail.com) письмо в спам попадает или нет? И ещё... а адрес в поле From: - он в домене google.com или нет?

Comment: @defrag Узко мыслите... В момент пересылки с почтового сервера отправителя на почтовый сервер назначения именно последний и является клиентом в этом сеансе обмена. И им, как я и сказал выше, тоже управлять не получится.

Comment: @Akina если в вашей терминологии "почтовый клиент адресата" и "почтовый сервер получателя" - одно и то же, то, да, и спорить тут не о чем. Я же понятия "почтовый сервер отправителя", "почтовый сервер получателя" и "почтовый клиент получателя" разделяю, чтобы понимать, на каком уровне (в каком звене цепочки) рассматривается вопрос отправки/доставки письма. То, что "сервер получателя" становится "клиентом" на момент smtp-сессии по отношению к "серверу-отправителю", это никак не связано с тем, каким "почтовым клиентом" пользуется юзер, забирая почту из ящика по POP3/IMAP.

Comment: @defrag Мы рассматриваем конкретный процесс - слив письма в спам. Это происходит в момент, когда письмо поступает в некую точку пересылки (конечную или промежуточную) из предыдущей точки пересылки. Точка, в которую поступило письмо, и в которой после поступления выполняется обработка письма и потенциально отправка его в спам, в этой пересылке является клиентом. Всё. Разница лишь в том, что конечный клиент сразу опустит письмо в спам, а промежуточный клиент (почтовый сервер - пересылки или получателя) лишь добавит к письму соответствующий заголовок с указанием спам-рейтинга.

Comment: @Akina если это описание вы вкладывали в смысл своего первого комментария про "Письмо в спам отправляет почтовый клиент адресата", то я полностью согласен и прошу прощения, за то, что доколупался до терминологии.

Comment: @JackShcherbakov через такие реквизиты сервера пробовали smtp.gmail.com:587 + SSL/TLS ?